# TensorFlow stopped working after installing opencv

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am working on projects that use TensorFlow and Keras and I did the hello-world MNIST project successfully and later I tried to run some other project and TF suddenly stopped working. Now it doesn't even work on the old project. I am working in conda envs and my editor is VSC. Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/miliv/MLRadionica/TensProba.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow import nn
  File "C:\Users\miliv\Miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\miliv\Miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package
```

I tried reinstalling TensorFlow a couple of times but it didn't help. The only thing that comes to my mind is that it has to do something with installing OpenCV maybe because of some packages, but I haven't changed anything else.

I have tried creating a new conda env with TF and without OpenCV but it still throws me the same error.

Comment: Check these links - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116456/no-module-named-tensorflow-python-tools-tensorflow-python-is-not-a-package, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34722

Answer (score 1):

Opencv installation with anaconda, downgrades a number of packages including numpy library to a lower version.., this support libraries cannot work with tensorflow after downgrade.. it messed be once

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost thing we needs to aware is , from installation perspective is there any micro level relationship between tensorflow and openCV , so that it could help us out in troubleshooting the above issue.

But yes    [this link will help you out in accomplishing your tensorflow/openCV setup installation](https://github.com/BiswajitMahato/Installing-Anaconda-Tensorflow-OpenCV-on-Windows)